# Installing Windows Service on a specific computer fails?

Tags: .net, windows, batch-file, windows-services

I have a Windows Service that is installed with the following code(bat file) :

```
@ECHO OFF

REM The following directory is for .NET 4.0
set DOTNETFX2=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
set PATH=%PATH%;%DOTNETFX2%

echo Installing IEPPAMS Win Service...
echo ---------------------------------------------------
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil "%~dp0MyApp5.WindowsService.exe"
echo ---------------------------------------------------
pause
echo Done.
```

This works great on almost all computers running Windows Server. Sometimes the bat file will have to be resaved as ANSI or UTF8 but after that it will in most cases work.

I have however runned in to a Windows Server 2012 computer where I get the following exception when using the install.but fil :

```
Installing IEPPAMS Win Service...
---------------------------------------------------
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Installation utility Version 4.0.30319.18010
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Running a transacted installation.

Beginning the Install phase of the installation.
See the contents of the log file for the C:\MyAppService54\MyApp5.WindowsService
.exe assembly's progress.
The file is located at C:\MyAppService54\MyApp5.WindowsService.InstallLog.
Installing assembly 'C:\MyAppService54\MyApp5.WindowsService.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole =
   assemblypath = C:\MyAppService54\MyApp5.WindowsService.exe
   logfile = C:\MyAppService54\MyApp5.WindowsService.InstallLog
Unable to create an instance of the MyApp5.WindowsService.ProjectInstaller insta
ller type.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the ta
rget of an invocation.
The inner exception System.NullReferenceException was thrown with the following
error message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..

An exception occurred during the Install phase.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to create an instance of the MyApp5.Win
dowsService.ProjectInstaller installer type.
The inner exception System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was thrown with
the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invoc
ation..
The inner exception System.NullReferenceException was thrown with the following
error message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..

The Rollback phase of the installation is beginning.
See the contents of the log file for the C:\MyAppService54\MyApp5.WindowsService
.exe assembly's progress.
The file is located at C:\MyAppService54\MyApp5.WindowsService.InstallLog.
Rolling back assembly 'C:\MyAppService54\MyApp5.WindowsService.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole =
   assemblypath = C:\MyAppService54\MyApp5.WindowsService.exe
   logfile = C:\MyAppService54\MyApp5.WindowsService.InstallLog
Unable to create an instance of the MyApp5.WindowsService.ProjectInstaller insta
ller type.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the ta
rget of an invocation.
The inner exception System.NullReferenceException was thrown with the following
error message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..
An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the System.Configuration.Inst
all.AssemblyInstaller installer.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to create an instance of the MyApp5.Win
dowsService.ProjectInstaller installer type.
The inner exception System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was thrown with
the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invoc
ation..
The inner exception System.NullReferenceException was thrown with the following
error message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..
An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the installation. This except
ion will be ignored and the rollback will continue. However, the machine might n
ot fully revert to its initial state after the rollback is complete.

The Rollback phase completed successfully.

The transacted install has completed.
The installation failed, and the rollback has been performed.
---------------------------------------------------
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I see that it gets a NullRef exception but I dont get this? It is working fine on all other computers. I know that this specific environment have some extra security rules, could it be this?

Comment: It could very possibly be due to "extra security rules".  Try using Process Monitor to see if there is an underlying file system operation that is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By enable all security settings in Explorer and do a re-download it worked. Im not sure how Explorer would be able to change content of a zip file based on security. I know about the block/unblock problem but this was not it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from the command promt:

```
>sc create "servicenameABC" binPath="path to your service location"
```

now go to services.msc you can find find your service(servicenameABC) listed there,
hope it helps..